# Is It Possible To Concatenate / Combine Video Files In WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I have written a Universal app for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 using C# that allows the user to record a video and send it to the customer, but now have a requirement to combine multiple videos into 1 video, but cannot see anything available in WinRT to support this.

Can it be done?

Comment: I have a feeling you'll need to know more about the file encoding in question. If it's as simple as combining two binaries into one, it's very doable. If the binaries have headers and metadata that need to be combined/removed, then you'll have to identify and find those. You have access to the byte streams directly and can manipulate them as such.

Comment: I am currently working on the assumption they are the same video format, resolution etc and recorded on the same device with the same camera

Comment: The format and such are not necessarily important. What you need to find out is the specification of the file encoding. Consider an encoding that is [Header] + [Video Data]. When combining the two files, if you did it straight you would get [Header1] + [Video1] + [Header2] + [Video2]. However, if you removed [Header2], then you would get [Header1] + [Video1] + [Video2]. It's not going to be nearly this simple. You will likely need to change the header of the video file to include things like an updated length.

Comment: It may also be possible to simply "record" the second video into the first. Consider the guide [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/04/22/Recording-Media-in-a-Windows-Store-App.aspx?Page=2) and its use of `_mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync`. It may be possible to simply hand it a stream that has video already in it. Create a new stream with length of the two combined, load up the first stream, seek to the right position, load up the second stream, write from there. You'll have to research and experiment to find the answer, as it's not a directly supported scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the videos have already been recorded to the drive you can concatenate them using a few different techniques depending on the platform. Let's start with Windows 8.1. On this platform we do not have an editing API and you will need to concatenate the files programmatically.

This can be done using the [Source Reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940436(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [Sink Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819461(v=vs.85).aspx). These two components allow you to read audio and video streams from a file and then write them out to another file. You can use one Source Reader per stream and a single Sink Writer.

The Source Reader is capable of parsing the file container and handing you either compressed or uncompressed samples. If all the input files have EXACTLY the same Media Types then you can theoretically write uncompressed samples to the Sink Writer. You will also need to configure the Sink Writer with this media type.

If you simply want to concatenate the files, you can read samples from Source Reader 1 and send them to the Sink Writer. Once you've written all the samples form Source Reader 1 move on to Source Reader 2, 3, etc.

The trick to get this right is to rebase the timestamps for the media samples on subsequent files. For example: If you have a frame rate of 30 FPS and the last time stamp written was 00:00:02:25 (SMTP non-drop) you will need to modify the first time stamp you get from the next source reader to be 00:00:02:26. Basically you will need to add 00:00:02:25+1 to each subsequent time stamp. You need to make sure that the time stamps increase monotonically at the expected cadence (30 FPS) and never repeat.

On Windows Phone 8.1 the problem is much easier to solve. With WP8.1 we introduced the [Windows.Media.Editing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.aspx) namespace to aid in video editing tasks. Using these APIs is really quite easy. Here is the 10,000 foot view:

1)  Create a [MediaComposition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.aspx) object.

2)  Set the encoding profile.

3)  Create [MediaClip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediaclip.aspx) objects that represent the files that you want to concatenate.

4)  Add the MediaClip objects to the MediaComposition and set the in and out points.

5)  Render the MediaCompositon to a file.

I wish I could offer a good sample for both of these but unfortunately AFAIK at this time we don’t have anything available. I have actually requested MediaComposition samples but I’m not sure about their status.

To request additional samples please go here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/requests

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: I have done the MediaComposition approach, but there is an audio problem where the video is combined but the audio plays double speed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861216/windows-phone-8-1-mediacomposition-audio-too-fast-when-stitching-videos